# Spring boot jdbc template not finding table in postgres under custom schema

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

My database has a few schemas and I created one called application to keep my application specific tables in. I added this schema to the search_path of postgres, but when I do a query using jdbc template it does not find the table. How do I make jdbc use the search_path to find the table that is being queried?

Answer (score 0):

There several options:

1) you can `set search_path to ..;` in the beginning of each session, or

2) you can `alter database yourdatabase set search_path to ...;`, or

3) you can `alter role yourdbuser set search_path to ...;`.

Options 2 and 3 will work only for new connections (don't forget to reconnect).

Also, you can set `search_path` in postgresql.conf, but this option is not that flexible if you have more than 1 database.